# Function argument passed in MusicSequenceUserCallback

Tags: swift, type-alias

The following func is part of MusicSequence in Core Audio

```
func MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(_ inSequence: MusicSequence, _ inCallback: MusicSequenceUserCallback?, _ inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> OSStatus
```

A MusicSequenceUserCallback is defined in the API as:

```
typealias MusicSequenceUserCallback = (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, MusicSequence, MusicTrack, MusicTimeStamp, UnsafePointer<MusicEventUserData>, MusicTimeStamp, MusicTimeStamp) -> Void
```

I am unclear how to pass a custom func into MusicSequenceSetUserCallback. Knowing about func types in Swift, I created a custom func with the exact same arguments as `MusicSequenceUserCallback` and tried to set it like this:

```
var argFunc: MusicSequenceUserCallback = myCallback
```

But I get the error `A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' of a literal closure` on the above line of code.

**Edit**

Here's the call back I wrote:

```
func myCallback(inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, sequence: MusicSequence, track: MusicTrack, eventTime: MusicTimeStamp, data: UnsafePointer<MusicEventUserData>, startSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp, endSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp) -> Void {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? At least enough for a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Cristik I added the callback I created, but that's really all the code involved here.

Comment: Is `myCallback` somehow an instance method of your class? If yes, then it won't work as you need a free function for the callback.

Comment: Great! that was it. If you want to put this as an answer I will mark it as correct if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving the error because the callback needs to be a free function, or a closure that doesn't any capture local context. Instance methods capture the `self` reference, thus you cannot use them as callbacks.

The solution is to either:

- declare `myCallBack` as a global function, or
- declare `myCallback` as an inner function/closure, and make sure it doesn't capture any local variables

If you need to make use of instance members of your class in your callback, you can achieve this by forwarding the callback from the free function to the instance of your class, via the `inClientData` argument:

```
class MyMusicClass {

    func myCoreAudioFunction() {

        .............

        func seqCB(inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, sequence: MusicSequence, track: MusicTrack, eventTime: MusicTimeStamp, data: UnsafePointer<MusicEventUserData>, startSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp, endSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp) -> Void {

            // we know for sure we have a MyMusicClass instance here, so the cast should be OK
            // care to be taken though to unregister the callback if the `MyMusicClass` instance gets deallocated, to avoid the zombie
            let client = unsafeBitCast(inClientData, MyMusicClass.self)
            client.musicSeqenceCallback(sequence, track: track, eventTime: eventTime, data: data, startSliceBeat: startSliceBeat, endSliceBeat: endSliceBeat)
        }

        MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(myMusicSequence,seqCB, unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self))
    }

    func musicSeqenceCallback(sequence: MusicSequence, track: MusicTrack, eventTime: MusicTimeStamp, data: UnsafePointer<MusicEventUserData>, startSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp, endSliceBeat: MusicTimeStamp) -> Void {
        // do anything you want here, there are no more restrictions :)
    }
}
```

Comment: in `let client = unsafeBitCast(data.memory, MyMusicClass.self)`, isn't it the `inClientData` parameter which should be cast instead ?